# I need an algorithm to calculate the outer boundary of a polygon

Tags: c, algorithm, polygon, computational-geometry

I have a polygon that can have an arbitrary number of self-intersections defined as an array of boundary points (two consecutive points form an edge in the polygon boundary). I want to calculate just the external boundary of the polygon (i.e. ignoring all the holes generated by self-intersections). (Not the convex hull, but I want the outer envelope of the polygon (all its edges should lie on the edges of the polygon boundary))

Here is some code below to generate a random polygon

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct Point2D
{
    double x;
    double y;
} Point2D;

int main()
{
    srand( time( NULL ) );
    const unsigned int POLY_SIZE = 20;
    //Polygon, two consecutive array indices form a line in the boundary of the
    // polygon. last point assumed connects to the first point
    Point2D *pPoly = malloc( sizeof( Point2D ) * POLY_SIZE );

    //Generate the Polygon
    const double polyRangeMax = 100.0;
    const double polyRangeMin = -100.0;
    const double polyPointRange = (polyRangeMax - polyRangeMin); 
    const double polyRangeScale = polyPointRange / RAND_MAX;
    for( unsigned int polyPointIdx = 0; polyPointIdx < POLY_SIZE; ++polyPointIdx )
    {
        pPoly[polyPointIdx].x = polyRangeMin + ( rand() * polyRangeScale );
        pPoly[polyPointIdx].y = polyRangeMin + ( rand() * polyRangeScale );
    }

    for( unsigned int polyPointIdx = 0; polyPointIdx < POLY_SIZE; ++polyPointIdx )
    {
        printf("<%f,%f>",pPoly[polyPointIdx].x,pPoly[polyPointIdx].y);
        if( polyPointIdx == POLY_SIZE-1 )
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }


    //Calculate Outer boundary of the polygon (it itself is a polygon), takes at most same amount of memory as pPoly above;
    unsigned int boundaryPolyPointCount = 0; //TODO calculate this alongside the poly
    Point2D *pOuterBoundaryPoly = malloc( sizeof( Point2D ) * POLY_SIZE );


    //TODO



    for( unsigned int polyPointIdx = 0; polyPointIdx < boundaryPolyPointCount; ++polyPointIdx )
    {
        printf("<%f,%f>",pOuterBoundaryPoly[polyPointIdx].x,pOuterBoundaryPoly[polyPointIdx].y);
        if( polyPointIdx == POLY_SIZE-1 )
        {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
    }

    free( pOuterBoundaryPoly );
    free( pPoly );
    return 0;
}
```

Every answer I see on Stack Overflow refers to JavaScript or Python libraries and never the actual algorithms themselves. If there is already an answer, let me know and I'll close this question, but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: One approach is to rasterize the polygon, enclose it in a bounding rectangle, then flood fill the region that's inside the rectangle and outside the polygon. It's not fast, but it's easy to code, and will give you the right answer.

Comment: Both JavaScript and Python libraries will be distributed as readable code (unless someone has obfuscated or minified it), and you may be able to determine the algorithm from those libraries.  It won't necessarily be simple, but it should be doable.

Comment: If you use Bentley-Ottman to find the intersections, then the next step is to [put your right hand on the wall and walk around the polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze-solving_algorithm#Wall_follower) in the clockwise direction. That requires three things. 1) Finding a vertex that's on the outer envelope. 2) Correctly choose the starting direction so that you're going in the clockwise direction. 3) At each intersection that presents a choice of line segments to follow, choose the one that keeps your right hand on the wall. That means turning left at a concave intersection.

Comment: OT: Notice that the random generation isn't guaranteed to produce a polygon. For instance the result maybe a number of polygons where each polugon shares at least one point with another polygon. As an example five points can generate two triangles instead of a single polygon.

Comment: An example of before/after for input edges and the expected polygon to calculate would help. For instance, what would the end-shape be that you are calculating for this input?: https://i.imgur.com/tNdyYVl.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bentley-Ottmann, and a sketch of an algorithm using it, were mentioned in the comments. That's the most efficient way of calculating the boundary. But if your polygon has less than, say, 1000 vertices and self-intersections, you can use a simpler algorithm and still get realtime performance.

First, identify an extreme vertex of the polygon (say, the one with the lowest X coordinate, with ties broken by the Y coordinate). Of the two edges coming out from that vertex, pick the one which is CW of the other (or equivalently has a lower y/x slope). That's your starting point and your starting edge, which are known to be in the boundary.

Now, loop over all the other edges in the polygon. For each one, check whether it intersects the current edge at a point "forward" (not necessarily >x or >y) of the starting point. Of the edges that intersect, track which one intersects the current edge *first* (that is, the intersection point is closest to the start point of the edge). Ignore edges which intersect at the start point. Remember, there's always at least one valid intersecting edge, the one which follows the current one in the original polygon. Whichever edge is closest, is the next segment in the boundary, and the intersection is the next starting point of that segment.

Eventually, the next starting point will be the original vertex. Then you know you're done.

This algorithm needs to be tweaked a bit if you expect to have points on line segments, or multiple edges intersecting in the same place. To handle these, only accept an intersection between the middle of one edge and the end of another edge if that other edge continues to the *left* of the current edge, and if multiple intersections are "nearest" then pick the one that results in the greatest *right* (clockwise) turn.

Comment: Sounds like a workable algorithm, but do you get real-time performance with 1000 vertices if, for each edge along the boundary, you have to check all other edges in the polygon?

Comment: @EricPostpischil, Sure, segment/segment is just a handful of adds/muls and a few compares, and finding the best intersection point doesn't even need a division until the end. It's not *moral* to brute-force it, but if the alternative involves coding up a RB tree or a spatial culling structure then brute force seems like the better part of valor for the OP.

Answer (score -2):

First, I have question.
What is your main role?

If you want to draw some polygon, you can use Direct2D library.
As you know, D2D support the powerful library to draw like D3D.
In this library, you can use function related to polygon, get the new vertices easily.

If your main role is mathematics algorithm, use the information such as line function, intersection line and etc.
For example, we select one line.
We have 2 vertices named v1, v2.
We can get the function of this line using v1 and v2.
Based this function, we can know other vertex position.
They have 3 choices such as right, left and on line.
If all of others vertices are same side, we can know this line is outer boundary.
...